# Why do I have to use .wait() with python's subprocess module?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running a Perl script through the subprocess module in Python on Linux. The function that runs the script is called several times with variable input.

```
def script_runner(variable_input):

    out_file = open('out_' + variable_input, 'wt')
    error_file = open('error_' + variable_input, 'wt')

    process = subprocess.Popen(['perl', 'script', 'options'], shell=False,
                           stdout=out_file, stderr=error_file)
```

However, if I run this function, say, twice, the execution of the first process will stop when the second process starts. I can get my desired behavior by adding

```
process.wait()
```

after calling the script, so I'm not really stuck. However,  I want find out why I cannot run the script using subprocess as many times as I want, and have the script make these computations in parallel, without having to wait for it to finish between each run.

**UPDATE**

The culprit was not so exciting: the perl script used a common file that was rewritten for each execution.

However, the lesson I learned from this was that the garbage collector does not delete the process once it starts running, because this had no influence on my script once I got it sorted out.

Comment: are you sure the second one completes? Do you mean the *same* invocation twice (same `variable_input`)?

Comment: The second completes as expected. I mean with different 'variable_input'. For example 'test_1' and 'test_2'.

Comment: what about trying to keep a reference to both processes, e.g. returning process and storing it in a variable?

Comment: This does not work actually -- implying that there is more than the garbage collector at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Unix, and wish to run many processes in the background, you could use `subprocess.Popen` this way:

x_fork_many.py:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time
import random
import gc  # This is just to test the hypothesis that garbage collection of p=Popen() causing the problem.

# This spawns many (3) children in quick succession
# and then reports as each child finishes.
if __name__=='__main__':
    N=3
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        x=random.randint(1,10)
        print('{p} sleeping for {x} sec'.format(p=os.getpid(),x=x))
        time.sleep(x)
    else:
        for script in xrange(N): 
            args=['test.py','sleep'] 
            p = subprocess.Popen(args)
        gc.collect()
        for i in range(N):
            pid,retval=os.wait()
            print('{p} finished'.format(p=pid))
```

The output looks something like this:

```
% x_fork_many.py 
15562 sleeping for 10 sec
15563 sleeping for 5 sec
15564 sleeping for 6 sec
15563 finished
15564 finished
15562 finished
```

I'm not sure why you are getting the strange behavior when not calling `.wait()`. However, the script above suggests (at least on unix) that saving `subprocess.Popen(...)` processes in a list or set is not necessary. Whatever the problem is, I don't think it has to do with garbage collection.

PS. Maybe your perl scripts are conflicting in some way, which causes one to end with an error when another one is running. Have you tried starting multiple calls to the perl script from the command line?

Comment: The problem was that the scripts used a common file that was overwritten. Now I run the programs in parallel with and without adding them to a list to keep the object safe from the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call wait() in order to ask to "wait" the ending of your popen.

As popen execute in background the perl script, if you do not wait(), it will be stopped at the object "process" 's end of life... that is at the end of script_runner.

Comment: In other words... If process get's out of scope it will become eligible for garbage collection. There is no way to know when the object will actually *be* collected but you shouldn't rely on that. Call wait explicitly.

Comment: @extraneon: Python is reference counted, so as soon as no one is holding a reference to `process` the object will be deleted and the subprocess stopped.

Comment: Regardless, it seems that even if I store the object in a list the processes are still interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

As said by ericdupo, the task is killed because you overwrite your `process` variable with a new `Popen` object, and since there are no more references to your previous `Popen` object, it is destroyed by the garbage collector. You can prevent this by keeping a reference to your objects somewhere, like a list:

```
processes = []
def script_runner(variable_input):

    out_file = open('out_' + variable_input, 'wt')
    error_file = open('error_' + variable_input, 'wt')

    process = subprocess.Popen(['perl', 'script', 'options'], shell=False,
                           stdout=out_file, stderr=error_file)
    processes.append(process)
```

This should be enough to prevent your previous `Popen` object from being destroyed

Comment: I tried this code exactly, but the outcome remains the same. I think there is more to it than the garbage collector.

Comment: strange, i tested it with a "time consuming" command, and it worked fine, problem must be somewhere else then. I'm sorry this doesn't solves your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry: you are right! The problem was that the scripts all used a common file that was overwritten each time. However, once I got it to work, it was not necessary for me to add the processes to a list to avoid the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do

```
list_process = []
def script_runner(variable_input):

    out_file = open('out_' + variable_input, 'wt')
    error_file = open('error_' + variable_input, 'wt')

    process = subprocess.Popen(['perl', 'script', 'options'], shell=False,
                           stdout=out_file, stderr=error_file)
    list_process.append(process)
#call several times script_runner
for process in list_process:
    process.wait()
```

so your process will be run in parallel